# Sync Google Keep to Apple Notes

Tags: data-synchronization, notes.app, android

I have an Android phone with a lot of notes in Google Keep. Is there an easy way to sync all my notes to my Mac so I can add, delete, and modify notes on both devices? (I've seen some paid apps, but I'd prefer to try something free if there's a way.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use keep.google.com on your mac!

Comment: Sorry I'm late to reply, but that's a great idea!

Comment: I posted an answer since my comment helped you, do upvote it if you'd like :D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google provides a simple way to get Google Keep on desktop—[keep.google.com](http://keep.google.com). It has all of the functionality of the Android and iOS mobile versions of Google Keep, just on Mac.

Here's a simple guide to Google Keep on all of your devices:

**iPhone/iPad:** [Download the iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-keep-your-thoughts/id1029207872?mt=8).

**Android phones and tablets:** [Download the Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&hl=en).

**Mac/Windows:** Use [keep.google.com](http://keep.google.com) or the [Google Keep Chrome Web Store app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki?hl=en) for easy offline access.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any more questions.